# Rate Limit in MS teams Bot framework-Clarification required

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I referred Msdn documentation:- [Rate limit in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit).
From this, I get to know that we can only send 15000 messages from bot to users per hour.
but I am confused with [bot per thread limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit#per-bot-per-thread-limit).

secondly, In order to handle 429 exception, I am now using this Code :-[Back off Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit#example-backoff).

earlier I was just using "connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync( (Activity)reply)" to send message to user.

Am I doing right, or is there any more precaution that I have to take care of? and how this exponential backoff will solve the rate limit?

Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes , you are on right path to handle 429 error for rate limit you need to implement back-off strategy. You can create a thread and make that thread sleep for sometime when 429 occurs and send the message again